# Unwrap Question

Tags: uv

I've been poking through models to see if I can learn how to do various things better and I have a question about unwraps. I can do my own seaming and what not well enough for me and can generally get what I want to to work to work but I'm curious about how some unwraps are made.

For example; These bars are three faced, open on the back to save tris and have no seams.

[image]

And are unwrapped on the UV like so;
[image]

Which looks to me like a 'Project from view' type thing but has all 3 faces neatly side by side and flat and maintains the distance between them.

If I make the same thing and unwrap it, it does not look like that. Hell, if I unwrap that same object again, it doesn't look like that. They've been able to get the same perfectly flat effect on everything even though the seaming doesn't seem to work. (Ugh the pun.)

Can anyone point me in the right direction, I'm probably missing something blindly obvious, but I thought I'd ask.

Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Answer (score 1):

Seams aren't necessarily shown.  Use "seams from islands" operation in UV editor to see your actual islands.  In the case of your bars, they are a different island than the surrounding faces.  That may be because of since-abandoned seams, or it may be because they're separate geometry, unconnected.

How would I make those bars?  I would probably do a basic unwrap (to minimize distortion) and follow it up with a pack islands operation-- on just the bars.  That would give me a general rectangle that I could scale into whatever space existed on the UV map.  And of course, I'd try to pick a space that had some relationship to the place that the bars existed in world space.